# No puedo guardar los datos del form en SQL con Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Estoy haciendo el back de un sitio web pero cuando deseo registrar un adiestrador y que lo impacte en mi base de datos no lo hace aunque sí me dice que el POST fue realizado con éxito. Estamos utilizando Django y SQLitle

Paso mis códigos para ver si alguien encuentra lo que falta o el error que debo estar cometiendo

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Adiestrador
from .forms import FormularioAdiestrador

def form1(request):
    formularioAdiestrador = FormularioAdiestrador()
    return render(request, "adiestradores/form1.html", {'formularioAdiestrador': formularioAdiestrador})

def procesar_formAd(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formularioAdiestrador = FormularioAdiestrador(request.POST)
        if formularioAdiestrador.is_valid():
            formularioAdiestrador.save()
            return redirect('form1')
    else:
        formularioAdiestrador = FormularioAdiestrador()
    return render(request, "adiestradores/form1.html", {'formularioAdiestrador': formularioAdiestrador})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Adiestrador

class FormularioAdiestrador(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Adiestrador
       fields = ['usuario_a', 'password_a', 'nombre_a', 'apellido_a', 'descripcion_a', 'telefono_a','mail_a', 'barrio1_a', 'barrio2_a', 'barrio3_a', 'barrio4_a', 'barrio5_a']
```

form1.html

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<main>
    <form id="form_adiest" action= "" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>Formulario de registro de adiestradores</h2>
        <fieldset class="recuadro">
            {% for field in formularioAdiestrador %}
            <div class="dato2">
                {{ field.label_tag }}
                {{ field }}
            </div>
            <br>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="enviar">
                <button type="submit" value="enviar" class="button">Enviar</button>
                <input type="reset" value="Limpiar" class="button">
            </div>
    </form>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Agradezco si me pueden orientar porque probé de todo. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Y el `action` de tu `form`?

Comment: Lo dejé vacío, que debería colocar? probé un par de cosas pero todas me daban error

Comment: Podés seguir [los tutoriales que están en la documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial04/) para orientarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya lo pude solucionar

Comment: El formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Pon como respuesta cómo resolviste tu problema, en base a [answer], y luego [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente pude solucionar el problema. El tema es que llamaba a un formulario distinto del cual debía hacerlo. Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda!